# Meaning of "one path to something"

Tags: meaning

In a construct "X is one path to Y", e.g. "Saving money is one path to wealth" does "one path" always implies that it is the only path? Or does it mean it is one of several ways to achieve Y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context it doesn't mean that the stated path (or 'way') is the *only* path - it means the opposite. It means there are *many* paths *of which this is but one*.

Saying "one" is often an alternative to using the indefinite article, for example:

- I have one dog
- I have a dog

If the writer meant to say that it was the *only* path to wealth, they would have used the definite article:

> Saving money is *the* path to wealth.